# Disabling only password ssh access for root

Tags: ssh, passwords, login, root, ssh-keys

I know it's possible to disallow `root` logins via ssh, and that it is a Good Idea™ to disallow `root` to *ever* login via ssh (preferring instead to use `sudo` or similar).

Is it possible to allow `root` to login *only* using keys, but to also allow `su -` to work from the commandline?

When I have disallowed `root` logins in the past, it has also killed the ability to do `su -` from another user.

If this is possible, how can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Put the following at the bottom of sshd_config:

```
Match User root
PasswordAuthentication no
```

You want to put this at the end of sshd_config, since everything after `Match User root` will apply only to root.  See [`sshd_config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) for more details.